# Make view controller in run time with xibs

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib

I want to make view controller at run time with the nib name like this,
But this is being crashed.

**Error**

> [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageViewApp.

```
let vc = UIViewController(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
```

When I try with the static values like this

`let vc = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)`, it is working.

This is the IBOutlet in MyViewController

I googled it but haven't found enough solution please let me know the solution.

Comment: Please mention your crash reason.

Comment: I am getting this error
'[<UIViewController 0x7fd3d95077f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageViewApp.'


This is the IBOutlet in MyViewController

Comment: Actually you are using  `UIViewController ` but your class name is `MyViewController `. That means xcode demanding the object of type `UIViewController` but you have `MyViewController` type of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove imageViewApp property IBOutlet from that view controller and give that ImageView a tag and access it with the tag.

Comment: you may be right but mean if I have more than 20 properties then I need to access it all via the tag, I think this is not useful as it looks.

Comment: Yes , it is not useful but as you need to create a ViewController at runtime , so there is no other way to access the property other then tag as the IBOutlet cannot be assigned.

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing a UIViewController and UIViewController has no imageViewApp property. You need to initialize your own subclass where you define that property, as you do in your second example.

Try something like this:

```
let vc = MyViewController(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
```

If your nib file has the same name as your class, you don't have to specify it:

```
let vc = MyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

Comment: It is working as I mentioned, But I want to make it runtime so view controller could of any type.

Comment: @GopalDevra Maybe you're looking for NSClassFromString? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to get the class(with xib) at the runtime by the name or may be with the xib file name.

Comment: @DrummerB If I am right. He is trying to initiate the xib from single method like if he have 5 xib then he just send xib as a param and then xib will be init from model class.

Comment: @GopalDevra are you making a model class for the xib to instantiate.??

Comment: Yes, like making a view controller instance from the storyboard dynamically by using just identifier.

Comment: @GopalDevra Bro you are creating VC by storyboard and initiating with XIB, then how it can be possible.

Comment: No, it is made from xib, I was just telling that I want to get that type of handling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136741/discussion-between-agent-stack-and-gopal-devra).